# Async Method Using Generic Func<T>

Tags: c#, generics, async-await, task, func

I have written the following method:

```
async Task<T> Load<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    T result = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        IsLoading = true;

        T functionResult = function.Invoke();

        IsLoading = false;

        return functionResult;
    });

    return result;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I simplify the code?
2. I can pass any *parameterless* method/function to this method to get a return type of any type. E.g.:

   ```
    string GetString()
   ```

   By saying:

   ```
    string someString = await Load(GetString);
   ```

   Is there a way I could make this method more generic so that I could pass methods with parameters as
   well? E.g. One single method that would also accept:

   ```
    string GetString(string someString)
    string GetString(string someString, int someInt)
   ```

   This might look like:

   ```
    string someString = await Load(GetString("string"));
    string someString = await Load(GetString("string", 1));
   ```

   This obviously doesn't work, but as the `Load<T>` method doesn't reference the parameters, I feel
   this should be possible somehow.

Comment: What is the purpose of `IsLoading`?

Comment: You don't normally need to `.Invoke()` a delegate. You can simply `T functionResult = function()`. [There is no difference](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WYAdsJgLIIAUMArADyXAB8mAZgK4UBjAJSFipcTADsPfgPpCA3GJIBfVMrKZ2tOI1bsufQSKIpxE6UYEA6AJIUAbgHsA1gFN5Ss6TUoVQA==) in the generated code, but I tend to associate `.Invoke()` to reflection-based dynamic invocation.

Comment: Are you sure you even *need* question 2? `await Load(() => GetString("string"))` should work fine.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `IsLoading` is a property I use for binding in WPF - this method is part of a base class called `LoadingViewModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I simplify the code?

You can both simplify it, and make it more correct. There are a few problems with the code as-written:

1. `IsLoading` is a UI-bound property, so it should be updated on the UI thread, not a background thread. Some frameworks like WPF on Windows allow you to bend the rules, but other XAML-based frameworks do not.
2. The code currently will not ever set `IsLoading` to `false` if the loading fails.
3. [`Task.Factory.StartNew` should be avoided; it's a dangerous, low-level method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). Use `Task.Run` if you need to run a method on a background thread.

```
async Task<T> Load<T>(Func<T> function)
{
  IsLoading = true;
  try
  {
    return await Task.Run(function);
  }
  finally
  {
    IsLoading = false;
  }
}
```

> Is there a way I could make this method more generic so that I could pass methods with parameters as well?

You can use lambdas for this:

```
string someString = await Load(() => GetString("string"));
string someString = await Load(() => GetString("string", 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for this - great answer!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I could make this method more generic so that I could pass methods with parameters as well?

```
async Task<R> Load<T, R>(Func<T, R> function, T parameter)
{
    R result = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return function.Invoke(parameter);
    });

    return result;
}
```

You can bundle into `T` whatever parameters the function needs.

If you still want individual parameters, you will have to create additional overloads.

You can also try `params` to pass an arbitrary number of parameters, but they must all be of the same type unless you use runtime polymorphism in some form.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can slightly shorten it to

```
Task<T> Load<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        var functionResult = function.Invoke();
        IsLoading = false;

        return functionResult;
    });
}
```

async and await are optional since you can return the task.
it maybe makes sense to use try ... finally block and update IsLoading = false in the finally

2. I agree with Robert Harvey [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65602958/14954633) regarding additional parameters

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I could make this method more generic

One option would be to nest it like so:

```
    public bool IsLoading { get; set; }
    
    public Task<string> GetString(string input) => Task.FromResult($"ret for input {input}");

    public async Task<TReturn> Load<TReturn>(Func<Task<TReturn>> cb)
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        var ret = await cb();
        IsLoading = false;

        return ret;
    }

    public async Task Demo()
    {
        var ret = await Load(() => GetString("input"));
    }
```

(I've made the GetString() method return a task too. Assuming it's easy to adjust if that makes no sense in your case.)